# Creating CSV on the Fly and Emailing, attachment not being created

Tags: php, csv

I inherited a PHP task from a fellow developer. Basically I need to make a CSV on the fly and email. Creating the CSV content is working, validated and fine. However when testing the email and the CSV I was successfully producing the email and attachment however both were blank with no text content? I made sure my script was clear of hidden characters (tabs, etc) and when retesting the email has content... but there is now no CSV atttachment!

This is my PHP code:

```
// Make CSV & Email
$csvString = chunk_split(base64_encode($csvString)); //CSV is produced earlier and is valid

// create the email and send it off

$mailSubject = "Daily CSV from the site";
$from = "root@localhost.com";
$headers =  "From: " . $from ."\n";
$headers .= 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\n";
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="----=_

NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC"' . "\n";

$message = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Hello

Oh look! Attached a CSV!

Regards

------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;  name="';

$message .= "$cvsName";
$message .= '"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="';
$message .= "$cvsName";
$message .= '"

';
$message .= "$csvString"; // was encoded
$message .= '
------=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC--
';

    // now send the email
    if (mail($email, $mailSubject, $message, $headers, "-f$from")) {
        echo("Message successfully sent!");
    } else {
        echo("Message delivery failed...");
    }
```

this is the email produced, notice there's no CSV attached but the email does contain the encoded CSV text/values. Can any one help?

[image]

this is the source code of the produced email:

```
Date: Fri, 05 Apr 2013 14:39:52 +0200
Subject: Daily CSV from the site
To: root@localhost.com
From: root@localhost
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: multipart/mixed;
boundary="-----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC"



This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

-----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC

Content-Type: text/plain;
charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit

Hello

Oh look! Attached a CSV!

Regards

-----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name="marcel.preukschat-Requested-19-03-2013.csv"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="marcel.preukschat-Requested-19-03-2013.csv"

marcel.preukschat-Requested-19-03-2013.csv

-----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC
```

Comment: `boundary` seems broken. There's a new line between `----=_` and `NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC`

Comment: Hi there, I've fixed that but the problem persists :(

Comment: I guess you should also get rid of trailing `--` at the end of last boundary

Comment: Strange, I've made sure all the boundaries are the same "-----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC" and they have no line breaks, however I have the same issue?

Comment: Doesn't seem like the csv file is encoded anymore, in your last source code

Answer (score 0):

I think this has to do with an unnecessary line break near the boundary definition. So let's make the boundary a little shorter to make things more obvious. Also see [this example of a multipart message](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MIME#Multipart_messages):

```
$headers .= 'Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary="NextPart_001"' . "\n";
```

and the parts below:

```
$message = 'This is a multi-part message in MIME format.
--NextPart_001
Content-Type: text/plain; charset="us-ascii"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit
Hello

Oh look! Attached a CSV!

Regards

--NextPart_001
Content-Type: application/octet-stream;  name="';
```

and

```
$message .= '
--NextPart_001--
';
```

Comment: Thanks for that, I've made sure all the boundaries are the same "-----=_NextPart_001_0011_1234ABCD.4321FDAC" and they have no line breaks, however I have the same issue?

Comment: I just tried your code and it produces a correct attachment when viewed with Apple Mail. Can you check the source code of the mail, for example by pressing Ctrl-U. It definitely looks like a problem with MIME not being detected.

Comment: I'mlooking at the messages via Outlook and it is not allowing me to View the source, however I found the emails in their folder (as I am testing locally) and opened them in NotePad++. I've added the source to the code above.